# Should I use data contained in an authentication JWT on the client-side?

Tags: authentication, client, jwt

A server provides a JWT to the client during authentication. That JWT contains information which is then later used by the server. For example, JWT may contain `permissions` array with the list of all permissions granted to a specific user.

Is it considered bad practice, if client parses the JWT and uses the permissions information contained within it? Is it better for client to make additional call to server (`GET /permissions`, for example) and behave according to that response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will strongly depend on a lot of small details; I'll try not to forget anything, but **in theory it should be fine to do so and if certain conditions are met I would not consider it a bad practice**.

OAuth2 states that access tokens should be opaque to clients, but JWT is just a token format ([Learn JSON Web Tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/)) and it's usage in other circumstances does not imply the same rules as OAuth2.

Also note that getting the information from an additional request has the same end result with the additional overhead of one more call. There would be a slight benefit if permissions are very volatile given you could repeat the calls.

However, the important part is more focused on what you mean by the client and how would the client use that information so I'll elaborate on this.

#### Assumptions:

1. the client you mention can be deployed as browser-based application (SPA's), native application or be some server-side component acting as a client.
2. both the server and client are controlled by the same entity.
3. the client and server components can be seen as a single application, that is, for an end-user the fact there's client and server components makes no difference; they use them as a whole.

#### Explanation

In this situation the token issued by the server is just a way for the client to later access protected resources without requiring explicit user authentication again; it's a mechanism to maintain a session between the two components.

**Given the same entity controls both the client and server, it's acceptable to treat the received token as a whitebox instead of a blackbox**. The client can then interpret the information in the token and take advantage of it to provide a better experience for the end-user. However, **this implies that the server will need to continue to validate the token and it's permissions accordingly**; any interpretation of the data by the client is purely to provide optional functionality.

Furthermore, for clients deployed to hostile environments like it would be the case **for a SPA application the decisions taken by looking into the data must only result in purely aesthetic decisions, as the user could fake the permissions data**. For example, you could use it to conditionally hide/disable some user interface just so that the user wouldn't have to click it to find out it wasn't allowed to do so.

A good analogy would be Javascript based input validation in web forms; you should do it for better user experience, but the server will need to do it again because the user can bypass the Javascript validation.

Comment: I also thought that using JWT as NOT opaque token is great because you get some value without paying much for it. But, such solution is vulnerable to the case, when a server changes JWT to an opaque token. Nevertheless, I'm going to use JWT's contents in the client app.